# Form Post Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post, callback

I'm hitting my head against the wall, struggling with a form that a need to post to my Arduino webserver and use the response from it to update a div. I already searched a lot about this, tried many examples I found including the one on [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Here is my code:

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script><script>
screen.lockOrientation("portrait") || screen.mozLockOrientation("portrait") || screen.msLockOrientation("portrait");
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $.post(url, {serial: $("#serial").val()})
 .done(function(data) {
 $("#monitor").append($(data));});});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body id="Body">
<h1>>Automação</h1>
<form name="form" id="form" class="form" action="URL" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="serial" name="serial">
<input type="submit" id="enter" value="Enter">
</form>
<div name="monitor" id="monitor" class="monitor"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to "mimic" the Serial Monitor from Arduino IDE to my webserver to access remotely.

The problem is no matter what I try the JavaScript don't execute the post request. The post is been executed, but seems to be from the form without the callback function (ignoring the server answer), because if I remove the method=POST or the URL from the form (letting it only in the JavaScript, for test purposes) the post don't run.

The response I get from the server it's things like this, that I wish to add to the monitor div:

```
freeMEMORY() = 6498 bytes<br/>
```

or

```
Arduino have been running for: 00 days 01 hours 25 minutes 25 seconds.<br/>
```

Comment: `console.log(data);`

Comment: when using `$(htmlstring)`, the htmlstring must start and end with html tags. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: No, i literally mean `console.log(data);`, on it's own, in the done callback. read the console afterwards.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your comment about the '$(htmlstring)'. And about the 'console.log(data);' as I expected, nothing happened, I got the same blank page result, that as I said on the post, I think it's because the POST is been made from the 'form' not from the 'javascript'.

Comment: Ah, of course. we're debugging from the wrong end then. Add a console.log before `$("#form").submit(...`, does it get called?

Comment: No, nothing "different" happens.

Comment: So, in your javascript console (F12), after loading the page, before clicking submit, you don't see anything in the console after adding console.log("Hello World!") before the .submit method?

Comment: Also... that line where you're calling screen.something, that line doesn't amke any sense. It's going to throw a syntax error (that, again, will be in your console (F12)) in any browser that doesn't support the first method. When such an error occurs, your submit event handler will not be bound.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand much of HTML, javascript and all this... I pressed F12 with a 'console.log(Hello World!") before the function and a another one saying Hello on the sucess callback, and what I got in the console is: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Serial.htm:18 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Remove the following line. `screen.lockOrientation("portrait") || screen.mozLockOrientation("portrait") || screen.msLockOrientation("portrait");`

Comment: Ok, now the first console.log Hello World appeared. But when I send the form the second dont appear, only the blank page.

Comment: replace `"Hello World"` with `$("#form")`, what is the result?

Comment: n.fn.init[0]context: documentselector: "#form"__proto__: n[0]

Comment: [context: document, selector: "#form", jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, toArray: function…]context: documentselector: "#form"__proto__: n[0]

Comment: @KevinB I know I'm newbie but please do not give up on me

Comment: Sorry, I left the office and went out for dinner. :)

Comment: This was the expected return from the console.log($("#form") input?

Comment: I expected to see an array containing a form, try this instead: `console.log($("#form").get());`

Comment: Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: well there's part of the problem. your selector isn't finding the form.

Comment: Where within the html page is your javascript located?

Comment: On the top, on the <head> part, shouldn't be there?

Comment: If it is located there, you need to wrap your code inside of an event handler that runs it after the document is ready, or after window load. `$(document).ready(function(){/* your code here */});` Otherwise it will try to find a form that doesn't exist yet. The other option is to move the code to before the closing body tag.

Comment: Oh God... Array[1]0: form#form.formlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Success then. Clicking the submit button shouldn't go to a white page anymore

Comment: It still goes to the white page :(

Comment: Just for testing purposes, add this to your form tag: `action="javascript:;"`, open the console, and then click submit.

Comment: I removed the method=POST from the form just to see if it would still execute a post (from javascript) or a get from the form default, and it executed a get.

Comment: With that action attribute value it shouldn't have performed a get or a post

Comment: hmm... seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LafxxLzb/

Comment: No, no, with that action nothing happened... After that I returned it to the correct IP and removed the method it did a get. Sorry for miss understuding.

Comment: Oh my God, THANKS VERY MUCH @KevinB !!! You saved my weekend, I was 3 days already struggling with this, almost hitting my head aganist the wall... I don't know exactly what I did, but it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* : I think the actual error is that you have `$(data)` where you should only have `data` (the argument you pass to you callback function (`.done`). I have edited my answer to reflect this.

I don't see where the JS variable `url` is set with the actual action page.

Try this, and document the `action` attribute on the `form` tag :

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), { serial: $("#serial").val() })
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#monitor").append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Acctually the url isn't a variable, I just removed the IP. It don't work, the POST is executed but the response is show in a blank page, not in the div (same as before).